# jQuery set image size after Popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an Image which opens in a Popup.

```
<a href="/images/image1.jpg" class="modal_link cboxElement" data-modal-title="Image1"><img src="/images/image1_small.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

The Popup looks like this then:

```
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 1223px; overflow: auto; height: 843px;"><img class="cboxPhoto" src="/images/image1.jpg" height="843" width="1223" style="width: 1223px; height: 843px; float: none;"></div>
```

Its an extension in Joomla which opens the Image in this kind of code.

I want to change the size of the loaded Image

```
jQuery('a.modal_link.cboxElement').click(function() {
    jQuery('img.cboxPhoto').css({'width':'auto','height':'auto'});
});
```

This is in a function which I call when the window is loaded.
Doesnt seem to work (I think because it fires the css styles instantly when the Link is clicked and doesnt wait for the Popup to load?)

How can I change that?

thanks

Comment: you want the image to fill the popup?

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle

Comment: The image already fills the popup. But its resized and I want the Image to be the original Size so I can scroll within the div id loadedcontent...